# Angular 11 Purple/Green Material Theme Not Working Correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular11

I added Angular Material to my project using `Angular-CLI`. I selected the `Purple/Green` pre-built theme. According to the [preview](https://material.angular.io?theme=purple-green) of the theme, the background color should be dark. But my background color still white. Why doesn't my background color change to dark? Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular Material docs say: “if your app's content is not placed inside a mat-sidenav-container element, you need to add the mat-app-background class to your wrapper element (for example the body). This ensures that the proper theme background is applied to your page.”

So did you put the mat-app-background class on the containing element?